# Retrieve all values of a field in a Cloud Firestore query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Each `user` in my `users` collection has three fields: `name`, `age` and `gender`.

I simply want to create a `List` of all names (the names are `String`s). How can I do this?

```
db.collection("phones").document(applicationID)
    .collection("users")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        // something
        val users: List<String> = result.document.data("name").values // this is obviously the wrong syntax 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate the documents in the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) that your listener receives (your QuerySnapshot variable is `result` here).  That QuerySnapshot contains a DocumentSnapshot for each document in the results.  QuerySnapshot implements Iterable, so you can just write a `for` loop to process each snapshot in order.  Or you can use some Kotlin convenience methods:

```
val names = result!!.map { snapshot ->
    snapshot["name"].toString()
}
```

`names` here will be a `List<String>`.